# RSpec: when using `subject`, I have to assign an object to an @variable to make it persist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have the following little helper in `application_helper.rb`:

```
def container_for(object, options = {})
  tag = options[:tag] || 'div'

  content_tag tag, id: dom_id(@user), class: dom_class(@user) do
    yield
  end
end
```

I want to test it like this:

```
describe '#container_for(object)' do
  subject { container_for(create(:user)) { 'Some content' } }

  it { should have_css 'div#user_1.user' }
end
```

But this results in the following error:

```
1) ApplicationHelper#container_for(object) 
   Failure/Error: subject { container_for(create(:user)) { 'Some content' } }
   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `to_key' for nil:NilClass
   # /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@base/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/record_identifier.rb:80:in `record_key_for_dom_id'
   # /Users/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@base/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/record_identifier.rb:62:in `dom_id'
   # ./app/helpers/application_helper.rb:65:in `container_for'
   # ./spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
   # ./spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb:20:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

When I assign the created user to an `@variable`, then it works:

```
describe '#container_for(object)' do
  subject { container_for(@user = create(:user)) { 'Some content' } }

  it { should have_css 'div#user_1.user' }
end
```

Why's that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the first case your `@user` instance variable inside helper is not initialized i.e. equal to `nil`, but in second case you assign instance of User object to it.

So, your `container_for` has side effect. It expect that `@user` has been initialized before.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to refactor the `@user` variable inside the helper method to point to the `object` parameter. Silly me. Thank you!